# Find first five non-zero terms of power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have the function f(x) = $\dfrac{2x}{\left(x-5\right)^2}$, and I'm supposed to "find the first five non-zero terms of power series representation centered at x = 0."

Using $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, the first non-zero terms I get are:

C1 = 2/25

C2 = 4/125

C3 = 6/625

C4 = 8/3125

C5 = 2/3125

However, WebWork marks these as incorrect. Any alternative methods or corrections to the work above are gladly appreciated.

Comment: those are the terms [wolfram alpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2F%5Bx-5%5D%5E2+series+at+x%3D0).

Comment: Does that mean the terms I listed are correct?

Comment: It seems so... Unless the question is asking for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, this an online system. Each of your coefficients is correct but perhaps you are missing the variables. For instance, the first term is $2x/25$ not its coefficients (because there can be constant terms in a Taylor Series). Similarly, the second term is $4x^2/125$, and so forth.

It could also be because it wants the coefficients of the terms but in order of powers, so it would $0$, $2/25$, $4/125$, etc. Though this seems less like than the first.

Overall, this seems less an issue of the mathematics - as your terms are correct, as it does how you are entering it or with the system itself. Just send a quick email to your instructor! They can see the solutions and thus perhaps more quickly tell what is incorrect about how the system wants the answer. As an instructor, I always found WebWork/WebAssign to be a bit wonky from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You don't have to compute the successive derivatives. Instead rewrite the fraction as
$$\frac{2x}{\left(x-5\right)^2}=\frac{2x}{25}\frac 1{\Bigl(1-\cfrac x5\Bigr)^2}=\frac{2x}5\left(\frac 1{1-\smash[b]{\cfrac x5}}\right)'$$
and use the power series expansion $\;\dfrac1{1-u}=1+u+u^2+\dotsm$

Answer (score -2):

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{2x}{\left(x-5\right)^2}
&=\dfrac{2x}{x^2\left(1-5/x\right)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(5/x)^n\\
&=\dfrac{2}{x}(1+2\dfrac{5}{x}+3(\dfrac{5}{x})^2+4(\dfrac{5}{x})^3+5(\dfrac{5}{x})^4+...)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{x}(1+\dfrac{10}{x}+\dfrac{75}{x^2}+\dfrac{500}{x^3}+\dfrac{3125}{x^4}+...)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{20}{x^2}+\dfrac{150}{x^3}+\dfrac{1000}{x^4}+\dfrac{6250}{x^5}+...)\\
\end{array}
$